# insert on duplicate not saving

Tags: mysql, sql, bulkinsert, insert-update

i have this sql which is suppose to update a table if an item does exists or insert it if it doesn't

```
INSERT INTO `mlm_user_settings` (`name`, `value`,`user_id`) 
VALUES ('notify_options','opt_none','7'), 
('chk_signup','0','7'),
('chk_activate','0','7'), 
('action','save','7'), 
('chk_acct','0','7'), 
('chk_message','0','7') 
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `value` = VALUES(`value`)
```

I have an unique constrain on `index (name , user_id)`

it does not update the values, but only works on inserting of new values
What could be the problem

**The table schema**

```
CREATE TABLE `mlm_user_settings` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `user_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `value` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  `created` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `user_id` (`user_id`,`name`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=10 ;
```

Comment: are those values already existing in your table?

Comment: some already exist, for example some of the zeros are suppose to be updated to '1'

Comment: if you have an unique index on(name,user_id) the ON DUPLICATE will be triggered only when the combined value in those 2 columns is the same-not the case in any of those values you insert.

Comment: the point  is if on inserting, a `(name, user_id)` already exists, then update the value to

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to define

```
UNIQUE KEY(name, user_id)
```

Simply defining an index won't prevent duplicates. You need to use the `UNIQUE` keyword.

Comment: @Smith no, you said you have an 'index'

Comment: @Smith please add the results of `show create table mlm_user_settings;` to your question

Answer (score 1):

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7e664/1

It works on this fiddle check the last insert.

ON these 2 last inserts

```
('chk_message','0','7'),
('chk_message','newvalue','7')
```

the constraint is trigger because the values in the 2 columns are the same 'chk_message','7'
so it updates with the new value:0 is updated with 'newvalue'.